# Referring to two sections

Tags: capitalization, writing-style

What is the proper way to refer to two sections in a single sentence (in a scientific text)?

In particular, should I use the word *section* twice, or should I use *sections*. If I use *sections* should I capitalize it?

For example:

> We discuss this issue in **Section 4 and Section 9**.
>
> We discuss this issue in **Section 4 and in Section 9**.
>
> We discuss this issue in **Sections 4 and 9**.
>
> We discuss this issue in **sections 4 and 9**.

Answer (score 0):

Of the four options you present:

> 1. We discuss this issue in Section 4 and Section 9.
> 2. We discuss this issue in Section 4 and in Section 9.
> 3. We discuss this issue in Sections 4 and 9.
> 4. We discuss this issue in sections 4 and 9.

Options (1) and (3) are the most common while (2) and (4) are acceptable but less common.

For all matters of publishing, ask your editor if there is a relevant style guide. Any of the four options *could* work but the best option will be the option the rest of the publication is using.

If there is no editor or style guide, I recommend using option (3).